# Reading content of json file in ionic app

Tags: json, angular, cordova, parsing, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build an app with ionic that reads data from a local `.json' file and uses this data to fill a page. But I'm already struggling with importing the file into the page. What I currently have is:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

interface Entry {
    name:           string,
    telephone:      string
}

interface EntryList {
    entryList:  Array<Entry>;
}

@Component({
    selector:    'page-list',
    templateUrl: 'list.html'
})
export class ListPage {

    entryList: EntryList;

    constructor() {
        this.load_entries();
    };

    load_entries () {
        this.entryList = JSON.parse(
            // ?
        )
    };
}
```

The `.json` file contains entries like:

```
[
{"name": "Person A","telephone": "1234"},
{"name": "Person B","telephone": "12345"}
]
```

I don't know how to proceed from here on. What's the right way to get my data into the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    this.load_entries();
};

load_entries(filePath: string) {  //filePath: 'assets/test.json'

    this.http
        .get(filePath)
        .subscribe((data) => {
           console.log(data);
        });
}
```

Of course, you have to import `HttpClient` first.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Do I have to add `HttpClient` somewhere else, like in `app.module.ts`?

Comment: Thank you for helping, but now when I open it, `uncaught exception: [object Object]` is logged to the console. I cannot catch this exception with a `try {} catch () {}`, though. I don't know what else might be wrong.

Comment: Okay, it was my fault. I thought I could import the file residing in the same folder, but it seems I must load it from the `assets` directory (as you wrote in the comment). Now it works. Thank you!